# iPhone submit button not displaying proper CSS decoration

Tags: android, html, ios, css, iphone

I have a mobile web app that has a button bar using square, flat buttons with flat, rounded end-caps.  Some of the buttons are links and some are Submit buttons and they are designed to look identical. Everything looks perfect on android devices but some of the CSS seems to be ignored on iPhone (iOS7) appearing 3-D with rounded corners. I designed the button using the following class:

```
.submit_button_green input {
height: 26px;
width: 61px;
border: 0px solid;
font-size 14px;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #00CC33;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top:-4;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #333;
}
```

Comment: If you copied and pasted the css you have a missing colon after `font-size`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS styles form items a lot differently, you can fix most by adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` to it.
Something like this should fix it:

```
.submit_button_green input {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* initial fix */
  height: 26px;
  width: 61px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px; /* you have a error here */
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #00CC33;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -4px; /* and here, -4 what? px? */
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #333;
  border-radius: 0; /* remove rounded corners */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible typo. Missing colon after `font-size`

```
font-size: 14px;
```

Check that